# Grafic problem with Pythondialog in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, python, kde, programming

I have a problem in Ubuntu 20.04 with pythondialog. As shown in the image:
[Dialog Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeoMA.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from dialog import Dialog
d = Dialog(dialog="Dialog", size="autowith")
d.msgbox("bla")
```

Well, it's not the "autowith" (change it with other values). In Ubuntu 18.04 I have not these grafic errors. The Problem appears even with inputboxes and other elements from "Dialog".

Do anyone know what's the reason behind this behavior?

Hope you can help me, guys :)

PS: A similar question was published by me in Stackoverflow, but it seems no one was interested in it. So I hope the Linux Community is forthcoming than Stackoverflow. Also the red boxes are from me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have installed Python3 binding for Dialog. It came from special [`python3-dialog`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-dialog) package, which installs all useful documentation into `/usr/share/doc/python3-dialog`. You can read this documentation using `dochelp` utility. The most useful folder is `/usr/share/doc/python3-dialog/examples/`, it contains 4 examples. Take a look at `/usr/share/doc/python3-dialog/examples/demo.py` first, it is [excellent](http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).

Then about your code - it uses wrong syntax. The correct variant is below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from dialog import Dialog
d = Dialog(dialog="dialog", autowidgetsize=True)
d.msgbox("bla")
```

For further experiments check the local (3.4.0, actual for 20.04 LTS) or [online](http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/doc/) (3.5.1, so newer) documentation.

Comment: So for me its not the "error" message inside the blue rectangle/box. I wanted to show that some "print" line´s are inside the blue box/rectangle. The reason why I ask this specific is, because if I made in another script a "ssh" connection...the "hello your conntcted to [and so on] message are inside the blue box.

I want some border or other soulution for this blue box, that not some print lines shown inside this blue box. (sorry for the missunderstanding)